# The Basic Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

In any n+1 integers there will be a pair which differs by a multiple of n.

I have tried to create a pigeon hole with numbers a0,a1,a2,...,an but i could not get a solution.

Comment: Assuming $n>1$ of course.

Comment: @JBKing: I daresay $n=1$ works, too.

Comment: True, I was thinking of $n=0$ where 1 integer doesn't make a pair.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint.** When you take numbers modulo $n$ (that is, find the remainder after dividing by $n$), there are only $n$ possible results.  Two numbers that share the same result differ by...

Answer (score 1):

Any number can be written  in term of n as 
Number = n * Quotient + remaineder 
Here  number is a1, a2 and so on , Quotient be anything depends on number 
But 
Remainder always lies between 0 to n-1(total count n).
So ,
Diff of two number=diff of Quotient * n + diff of remainder

Diff of two number is not equal to multiple of n if and only if  diff of remainder is not equal to 0 or remainder should be unique. But it impossible to generate unique remainder other than 0 to n-1.